How to change output to timestamps for ffmpeg freezedtect?
ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=5" -map 0:v:0 -f null -

Will output:
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 324.266667
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 5.066667
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 329.333333
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 329.333333
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 5.066667
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 334.4

I want output converted to hh-mm-ss format. I also want to exclude duration and end.
Example of desired output:
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 00:05:24
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 00:05:29

Thanks in advance

not sure about reformatting the timestamps, but if you just want freeze_start, the 'lazy' option is to pipe it through grep, assuming you're on linux
